Group temporally contiguous values
I'm trying to group Values that are temporally contiguous. However, all I can achieve is flag those Values that are contiguous (with a "yes"). The problem here is that two different groups may end up with consecutive "yes" and are hence indistinguishable:
df %>%
  mutate(contiguous = ifelse(Endtime_ms == lead(Starttime_ms)|Starttime_ms == lag(Endtime_ms), "yes", "no"),
         grp = consecutive_id(contiguous)
  ) 
# A tibble: 20 × 5
   Value                            Starttime_ms Endtime_ms contiguous   grp
   <chr>                                   <dbl>      <dbl> <chr>      <int>
 1 "on this"                                 210        780 NA             1
 2 "okay"                                   3403       3728 no             2
 3 "cool thanks everyone um"                4221       5880 no             2
 4 "so yes in"                              5910       6900 yes            3 # one group
 5 "terms of our"                           6900       8370 yes            3 # one group
 6 "partnership"                            8370       8970 yes            3 # one group
 7 "projects"                               8970       9480 yes            3 # one group
 8 "what have we"                           9510      10080 yes            3 # another group
 9 "got on the"                            10080      11293 yes            3 # another group
10 "horizon? "                             11293      11960 yes            3 # another group
11 "let's have a look so the"              11980      13740 no             4
12 "LGBTQ plus"                            13813      16110 no             4
13 "city labs"                             16260      17070 yes            5
14 "have now"                              17070      17910 yes            5
15 "been um"                               17940      19320 no             6
16 "agreed in"                             19350      20190 yes            7
17 "terms of the"                          20190      20760 yes            7
18 "date so"                               20760      21330 yes            7
19 "we're looking at the fifteenth"        21330      22530 yes            7
20 "sixteenth"                             22860      23490 NA             8

The desired output is this:
   Value                            Starttime_ms Endtime_ms contiguous   grp
   <chr>                                   <dbl>      <dbl> <chr>      <int>
 1 "on this"                                 210        780 NA             1
 2 "okay"                                   3403       3728 no             2
 3 "cool thanks everyone um"                4221       5880 no             2
 4 "so yes in"                              5910       6900 yes            3 
 5 "terms of our"                           6900       8370 yes            3 
 6 "partnership"                            8370       8970 yes            3 
 7 "projects"                               8970       9480 yes            3 
 8 "what have we"                           9510      10080 yes            4
 9 "got on the"                            10080      11293 yes            4
10 "horizon? "                             11293      11960 yes            4
11 "let's have a look so the"              11980      13740 no             4
12 "LGBTQ plus"                            13813      16110 no             5
13 "city labs"                             16260      17070 yes            6
14 "have now"                              17070      17910 yes            6
15 "been um"                               17940      19320 no             7
16 "agreed in"                             19350      20190 yes            8
17 "terms of the"                          20190      20760 yes            8
18 "date so"                               20760      21330 yes            8
19 "we're looking at the fifteenth"        21330      22530 yes            8
20 "sixteenth"                             22860      23490 NA             9

Data:
df <- structure(list(Value = c("on this", "okay", "cool thanks everyone um", 
                               "so yes in", "terms of our", "partnership", "projects", "what have we", 
                               "got on the", "horizon? ", "let's have a look so the", "LGBTQ plus", 
                               "city labs", "have now", "been um", "agreed in", "terms of the", 
                               "date so", "we're looking at the fifteenth", "sixteenth"), Starttime_ms = c(210, 
                                                                                                           3403, 4221, 5910, 6900, 8370, 8970, 9510, 10080, 11293, 11980, 
                                                                                                           13813, 16260, 17070, 17940, 19350, 20190, 20760, 21330, 22860
                               ), Endtime_ms = c(780, 3728, 5880, 6900, 8370, 8970, 9480, 10080, 
                                                 11293, 11960, 13740, 16110, 17070, 17910, 19320, 20190, 20760, 
                                                 21330, 22530, 23490)), row.names = c(NA, -20L), class = c("tbl_df", 
                                                                                                           "tbl", "data.frame"))


Hm, maybe the downvoter lets me know why they downvoted this?

I suspect this is impossible as long as we do not have additional information about the grouping process. Perhaps, this is why one has downvoted your question?

I wonder why your first contiguous value is NA. Shouldn't it be "no"?  Suppose the Endtime_ms was 3403. Would contiguous then be a "yes" for the first 2 rows?

Yes, absolutely, this should be "no".

Trying again....  get the feeling that starting with is_contig <-which( data[ -1,Starttime_ms] == data[ 1:19, Endtime_ms]) , then doing the obvious application of those indices to set "yes" or "no" .

On top of what you have already, you can use igraph package for clustering and assigning group labels lbl for intermediate tagging, then update grp values according to the contiguous status
library(igraph)
df %>%
   mutate(
      contiguous = ifelse(Endtime_ms == lead(Starttime_ms) | Starttime_ms == lag(Endtime_ms), "yes", "no"),
      grp = consecutive_id(contiguous)
   ) %>%
   mutate(
      lbl = {
         # create a graph where the edges are built based on `Starttime_ms` and `Endtime_ms`. The vertices are clustered if the edges are linked. 
         graph_from_data_frame(df[-1]) %>%
            components() %>%
            membership()
      }[as.character(Starttime_ms)]
   ) %>%
   # refresh `lbl`, so `lbl` collapse into one cluster if the associated `grp` value is `no`; Otherwise, we retain the `lbl`
   mutate(lbl = coalesce(ifelse(contiguous == "yes", lbl, min(lbl)), lbl), .by = grp) %>%
   # re-calculate the grouping info based on updated `lbl`
   mutate(grp = consecutive_id(lbl)) %>%
   # remove auxiliary variable `lbl`
   select(-lbl)

which gives
# A tibble: 20 × 5
   Value                            Starttime_ms Endtime_ms contiguous   grp
   <chr>                                   <dbl>      <dbl> <chr>      <int>
 1 "on this"                                 210        780 NA             1
 2 "okay"                                   3403       3728 no             2
 3 "cool thanks everyone um"                4221       5880 no             2
 4 "so yes in"                              5910       6900 yes            3
 5 "terms of our"                           6900       8370 yes            3
 6 "partnership"                            8370       8970 yes            3
 7 "projects"                               8970       9480 yes            3
 8 "what have we"                           9510      10080 yes            4
 9 "got on the"                            10080      11293 yes            4
10 "horizon? "                             11293      11960 yes            4
11 "let's have a look so the"              11980      13740 no             5
12 "LGBTQ plus"                            13813      16110 no             5
13 "city labs"                             16260      17070 yes            6
14 "have now"                              17070      17910 yes            6
15 "been um"                               17940      19320 no             7
16 "agreed in"                             19350      20190 yes            8
17 "terms of the"                          20190      20760 yes            8
18 "date so"                               20760      21330 yes            8
19 "we're looking at the fifteenth"        21330      22530 yes            8
20 "sixteenth"                             22860      23490 NA             9


Very cool! Can you explain the mutate clause after mine?

@ChrisRuehlemann see the comments in the code

You could use the following:
mutate(df, 
       c1=Starttime_ms==lag(Endtime_ms, default=-1),
       c2=Endtime_ms==lead(Starttime_ms, default=-1),
       contiguous = c1 | c2,
       grp1=consecutive_id(contiguous) +
            cumsum(!c1 & c1!=c2 & contiguous==lag(contiguous))) |>
  select(-c(c1, c2))

# A tibble: 20 × 5
   Value                            Starttime_ms Endtime_ms contiguous  grp1
   <chr>                                   <dbl>      <dbl> <lgl>      <int>
 1 "on this"                                 210        780 FALSE          1
 2 "okay"                                   3403       3728 FALSE          1
 3 "cool thanks everyone um"                4221       5880 FALSE          1
 4 "so yes in"                              5910       6900 TRUE           2
 5 "terms of our"                           6900       8370 TRUE           2
 6 "partnership"                            8370       8970 TRUE           2
 7 "projects"                               8970       9480 TRUE           2
 8 "what have we"                           9510      10080 TRUE           3
 9 "got on the"                            10080      11293 TRUE           3
10 "horizon? "                             11293      11960 TRUE           3
11 "let's have a look so the"              11980      13740 FALSE          4
12 "LGBTQ plus"                            13813      16110 FALSE          4
13 "city labs"                             16260      17070 TRUE           5
14 "have now"                              17070      17910 TRUE           5
15 "been um"                               17940      19320 FALSE          6
16 "agreed in"                             19350      20190 TRUE           7
17 "terms of the"                          20190      20760 TRUE           7
18 "date so"                               20760      21330 TRUE           7
19 "we're looking at the fifteenth"        21330      22530 TRUE           7
20 "sixteenth"                             22860      23490 FALSE          8

The cumsum is needed to split the consecutive TRUE groups that are separate. Note that you had an error on row 12.

Nice! Creating temp vars on one condition and changing one of those does the trick. Wanted to post a similiar idea. (+1)

I think your 2nd and 3rd row should be group 2 (see OP's desired output)

@ThomasIsCoding Well - yes, but according to their description, the first 3 rows should be one group.

Like the compact cumsum. For educational purposes, could you comment on the default = -1 for c1, c2?, as one gets the sense from ?dplyr::lag, that sign, +- is a function of whether it is lead or lag employed when a non-signed integer is used as pad.

I just wanted to pad NA with any (arbitrary) value. Maybe 0 would have been better, and it doesn't matter for the last row.

In the attempted solution, the first line of contiguous is only NA because the default argument was missing in dplyr::lead and dplyr::lag functions. @Edward is right and the first line should be "1".
That said, here's a take based on pivot_longer/pivot_wider without leads and lags:
library(tidyverse)

# ----------------
df %>% 
  rowid_to_column("id") %>% 
  pivot_longer(ends_with("ms")) %>% 
  
  add_count(value, name = "group_id") %>% 
  mutate(group_id = if_else(group_id == 2, consecutive_id(group_id), NA_integer_)) %>% 
  mutate(.by = id, flag = if_else(any(!is.na(group_id)), "yes", "no")) %>% 
  with_groups(id, \(x) fill(x, group_id, .direction = "downup")) %>% 
  mutate(group_id = consecutive_id(group_id)) %>% 

  pivot_wider(id_cols = c(id, Value, group_id, flag))

The output:
# A tibble: 20 × 6
      id Value                            group_id flag  Starttime_ms Endtime_ms
   <int> <chr>                               <int> <chr>        <dbl>      <dbl>
 1     1 "on this"                               1 no             210        780
 2     2 "okay"                                  1 no            3403       3728
 3     3 "cool thanks everyone um"               1 no            4221       5880
 4     4 "so yes in"                             2 yes           5910       6900
 5     5 "terms of our"                          2 yes           6900       8370
 6     6 "partnership"                           2 yes           8370       8970
 7     7 "projects"                              2 yes           8970       9480
 8     8 "what have we"                          3 yes           9510      10080
 9     9 "got on the"                            3 yes          10080      11293
10    10 "horizon? "                             3 yes          11293      11960
11    11 "let's have a look so the"              4 no           11980      13740
12    12 "LGBTQ plus"                            4 no           13813      16110
13    13 "city labs"                             5 yes          16260      17070
14    14 "have now"                              5 yes          17070      17910
15    15 "been um"                               6 no           17940      19320
16    16 "agreed in"                             7 yes          19350      20190
17    17 "terms of the"                          7 yes          20190      20760
18    18 "date so"                               7 yes          20760      21330
19    19 "we're looking at the fifteenth"        7 yes          21330      22530
20    20 "sixteenth"                             8 no           22860      23490

Created on 2024-05-06 with reprex v2.1.0
